Javascript incorrectly convert binary data to string
I'm writing a JS script on a third-party platform for business. Now, I get a raw encrypted binary data from a base64 string and I need to set the classA's property with the raw data.
This is a sample data encoded with base64:
nzx4qnf7g23hNvS1Fj4iMU56uGwhCY7CazUsEt5gPOs=

This is the corresponding raw binary form:
b'\x9f<x\xaaw\xfb\x83m\xe16\xf4\xb5\x16>"1Nz\xb8l!\t\x8e\xc2k5,\x12\xde`<\xeb'

The script:
var encryped_b64 = 'nzx4qnf7g23hNvS1Fj4iMU56uGwhCY7CazUsEt5gPOs=';
classA.data.raw = Buffer.from(encryped_b64 , 'base64').toString('binary');
classA.send_data();

But it turns out that the converted result is not as expected:
b'\xc2\x9f<x\xc2\xaaw\xc3\xbb\xc2\x83m\xc3\xa16\xc3\xb4\xc2\xb5\x16>"1Nz\xc2\xb8l!\t\xc2\x8e\xc3\x82k5,\x12\xc3\x9e`<\xc3\xab'

The script is running on a customized node.js environment which provides really limited feature, and I got no idea how to convert it correctly.

I suspect that whatever send_data() is, passes that variable as a string, which is then encoded as UTF-8, which explains the addition of the C2 and C3. The 9F is interpreted as a Unicode code point 0x9F, which when encoded with UTF-8 (a multi-byte encoding of Unicode, i.e. a way to represent the code point as raw bytes), is [0xC2, 0x9F]. See: Buffer.from(String.fromCodePoint('0x9f'), 'utf-8'). What you need to do instead is either send it encoded as it is and decode it at the server, or send it as a multipart/form-data request with the raw bytes. Please show send_data().

@Kulo Does it work if you instead use: classA.data.raw = "9f3c78aa77fb836de136f4b5163e22314e7ab86c21098ec26b352c12de603ceb"; then followed by the usual classA.send_data();?
